# How does wind chakra amplify water style?

Tags: naruto

So in Naruto, wind chakra is strong against electric and weak against fire as it amplifies the fire.

But at the same time, when naruto does the Toad-water-pistol collaboration ninjutsu with the frogs, his wind style amplifies water style..how is that possible?

Doesn't wind style amplify fire? Then how come its amplifying water too? Wind and water aren't related in the chakra relation circle thing..

Answer (score 3):

Weakness has nothing to do with whether or not two elements amplify each other. It has to do more with the fact that both chakra natures are coming from the same side (either the same person or allies).

Some elements' weaknesses work by the "stronger" element canceling out the "weaker" one (e.g. water canceling out fire). Others work by the "weaker" amplifying the "stronger" one (e.g. lightning amplifying water, wind amplifying fire).

However, if one person (kekkei genkai/two chakra natures) or two allies (cooperation jutsu) are using a technique, the chakra will generally combine to create a stronger technique (because energy will be released even if two elements cancel each other). For example, [ice style = water + wind](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Release), and [vapor style = water + fire](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boil_Release). This is similar in that Naruto's wind style is [augmenting the impact force of the water](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Typhoon_Water_Vortex_Technique) via a cooperation jutsu.

Comment: oh..so both the chakras combine..